# Homology of real projective plane with two points identified

Tags: algebraic-topology

What is the delta homology of the real projective plane with two points identified. I can't think of any space that it retracts that I can find a delta structure does anyone have any idea

Comment: Isn't the space equivalent to $\mathbb{R}P^1 \vee S^1$?

Comment: One way to find a delta structure is as follows. First represent the projective plane as a disk with antipodal points of boundary identified. Draw in a diameter and put a vertex at the center. The two endpoints of the diameter are one vertex since they are identified. Now glue the center vertex to this identified vertex so all three vertices in the picture are the same.

Comment: I'd say it's equivalent to $\Bbb R P^2 \vee S^1$. Identifying two points it's the same as attaching a path to these two point. by contracting any simple path in $\Bbb R P^2$ connecting those two points and using the Homotopy extension property, you get the claimed homotopy equivalence

Comment: "delta homology" and "delta structure" sound like interesting concepts that weren't recognised back in the day when I first learnt some algebraic topology. What do these terms mean? Clearly if you identify two points on a connected manifold $M$, the result is homotopy equivalent to the wedge $M \lor S^1$. What more do you (or I) need to know?

Comment: @RobArthan: Hatcher uses delta complexes. They are basically simplicial complexes where the faces of a simplex need not be distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ with two points $a,b$ identified is homotopy equivalent to $X$ plus a line segment between $a,b$. If $a,b$ are in the same path component of $X$ then you can slide one to the other and your segment becomes a loop, so you get $X \vee S^1$.

All this might depend on $a,b$ being nondegenerate in some way, but that shouldn't be a problem in a cell complex.